# How sticky is Stick Together?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class

In Pathfinder, I have been looking through the vastly under appreciated Cavalier class and its *Tactician* abilities (causing any ally within 30 feet to adopt their selected Teamwork feat). One of the more notable feats that can be spread is the *Stick Together* feat, which drags all allies with this feat along with the user when they move at the cost of everyone else becoming staggered.

My questions are: 1) Can a character that was moved by an ally's *Stick Together* action use the ability to move the group further ahead? (Human moves group 30 feet, then allied Dwarf moves group 20 more feet on his turn while staggered)

2) If a character using *Stick Together* uses an acrobatics check to clear a gap, does the user move alone, uses his skill roll for the whole party or forces everyone else to make a roll with them on the jump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: **No**

Stick Together's full description reads thus:

> When an adjacent ally with this feat moves, you can move up to your
>   speed as an **immediate action,** as long as your movement ends adjacent
>   to that ally. If you do so, you are staggered on your next turn. This
>   movement provokes attacks of opportunity as normal.

An immediate action consumes your next turn's swift action. Thus, a single person can only benefit from Stick Together once per round (and doing so leaves them Staggered). Since the Staggered condition prevents them from taking both a move and a standard action, this means that benefiting from Stick Together effectively costs both their Swift and their Move action for the next round.

Additionally, since it does not allow them move more than their speed, a character with a 20-foot speed would not be able to use Stick Together to "keep up" with a character moving 30 feet in most circumstances.

There is no way that I can think of to use Stick Together to move faster than double-moving on your turn.

2: **Probably Not**
This is heavily subject to how your GM interprets the phrase, "Up to your speed." Most characters do not have a Fly, Climb or Swim speed, and thus cannot normally move through the air, along walls, or underwater.